# Why my custom hook causes infinite data refetching?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My component gets the hashed-id from the query string, then calls api with that hash to fetch a post for review.

eslint forces me to add my custom hook to dependency array.

```js
  fetchpost();
  }, [query]);
```

But doing this causes an infinite loop. In order to stop it I need to disable this eslint rule, as seen below.

```js
// component file 
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const query = useQuery();
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  const [hash, setHash] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchpost = async () => {
      const hash = query.get("hashed_id");
      const post = await fetchReviewPost(
        `/api/posts/${hash}/review`
      );
      setHash(hash);
      setPost(post);
    };

    fetchpost();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

// utils file 
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const getCurrentURL = () => {
  return document.URL;
};

export const useQuery = () => {
  const queryString = useLocation().search;

  return new URLSearchParams(queryString);
};
```

Dan Abramov writes `An infinite loop may also happen if you specify a value that always changes in the dependency array.`

Is that the case here? Is `query` reference different on every render? And why eslint wants to put it in a dependency array?

He also says `removing a dependency you use (or blindly specifying []) is usually the wrong fix.` Which I sort of did by disabling the eslint rule.

Any thoughts?

Comment: useQuery comes from react-apollo or is it a custom hook of yours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to keep sticking to eslint suggestions and using the `useQuery` hook, here is an alternative way:

```
  // component file 
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const q = useQuery();
  const [query] = useState(q);
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  const [hash, setHash] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchpost = async () => {
      const hash = query.get("hashed_id");
      const post = await fetchReviewPost(
        `/api/posts/${hash}/review`
      );
      setHash(hash);
      setPost(post);
    };

    fetchpost();
  }, [query]);
```

At this point the `query` value keeps constant across the subsequent function calls.

However, I'd remove the `useQuery` hook, and place its content straight into the `fetchpost` function.

Comment: That works :) Was I right when I was thinking that query has a different reference on every render thus causing rerender?

Comment: exactly. The comparison is made by reference.